# C++ Type safe API for glorified strings

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I'm trying to provide type safety for my APIs which take many "types" of strings that have different meaning.
Since these are just strings, and it is exactly the type for those values, I could obviously create a special class for each type, but all of them will look exactly the same, so I would like to make it generic.

In my attempt I just used type aliasing with a "unique" set of characters as the template arguments of the class template, but I would like to know if there is a "best known way" or something simpler than what I did below, to allow type safe APIs for "glorified" types, in a generic way (i.e without manually creating a class for every type)?

Preferably, such a solution would also generate a clear compile error message when using the wrong type.

```cpp
template<char ... name>
struct GlorifiedString
{
    explicit GlorifiedString(std::string s) : m_s(std::move(s)) {}
    const std::string& Value() const { return m_s; }
    std::string& Value() { return m_s; }
private:
    std::string m_s;
};

using ID = GlorifiedString<'I', 'D'>;
using QR = GlorifiedString<'Q', 'R'>;
using Address = GlorifiedString<'A','d','d','r','e','s','s'>;

void UpdateID(ID id){ /*...*/ }

int main() {

    ID id("123456789");
    QR code("123456789");
    Address addr("123 street st. Country");

    UpdateID(id);
    UpdateID(code); // <-- error: could not convert 'code' from 'GlorifiedString<'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr<expression error>>' to 'GlorifiedString<'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr<expression error>>'
    UpdateID(addr); // <-- error: could not convert 'addr' from 'GlorifiedString<'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr<expression error>>' to 'GlorifiedString<'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr<expression error>>'
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType

Comment: "*error: could not convert*" Do you *intend* for those to be errors, or are you trying to find a way to make `UpdateID` actually take `code` and `addr`?

Comment: Yes I want those calls to be error, just with a better error message

Comment: bad news that `static_assert` show error message which must be *string literal*, so we may not be able to show infos with **ID** instead of **GlorifiedString<'I', 'D'>**.